# C++ what does the unary operator used on class mean ? (Class::Class)

Tags: c++, class, unary-operator

I followed the youtube tutorial and i can create basic class but the tutorial doesn't explain how the Class::Class works, I search google but i only know that it is called unary operator and what it does but I dunno what it do with Class, please help me explain about this and thanks very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Class
class Mother {

    public:
        void msg();

};

void Mother::msg(){ //This is where i don't undrstand
    std::cout << "Go home early sweetie" << std::endl;
}

class Daughter: public Mother {

    public:
        void getMsg();

};

void Daughter::getMsg(){ //Same as this
    std::cout << "Mom said ";
    msg();
}


//Main
int main() {

    Daughter lucy;
    lucy.getMsg();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a unary operator in your code, but as you are asking about the class name in front of the function in `Mother::msg` and `Daughter::getMsg`: note that the function is defined outside the class declaration. So you have to give the name of the class if you define a member function, otherwise the function would be global. Is it this what you are asking about? Why the `Mother::` is there? Or are you asking about constructors?

Comment: Yes @Karsten, I'm asking about the class name in front of the function

Comment: Also can u please tell me what does this mean? `Class::Class :var {...}` does that mean the variable is defined inside the class right? same concept as what u have said?

Comment: I don't know where you read what you read but that's not "the unary operator". Instead of "searching Google" and watching random tutorials on YouTube, read a textbook!

Comment: "unary operator" means an operator that takes only one argument.  `::` is a binary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class, you declare a member function `msg()`, but you don't actually define it there:

```
class Mother {
public:
    void msg();
};
```

Usually this declaration goes into a .h file, and now you want to put the function definition in a .cpp file. But you can't just write

```
void msg() 
{
  // ..
}
```

in your .cpp file, as this would define a global function, not a member function. Also, the compiler cannot know that you are really trying to define the member function, as several classes could be declared at this point. So you need a way to tell the compiler that the function lives inside the `Mother` class:

```
void Mother::msg()
{
  //..
}
```

The same syntax is used for namespaces. Take the class `string` from the `std` namespace:

```
std::string myString;
```

EDIT:
A special function is the constructor, which has the same name as the class. The definition would look like this:

```
Mother::Mother()
{
  // ..
}
```

In this constructor, you can initialize member variables and generally set up the class instance. All member variables are created at that point. Now what if you have a member variable of a type where you want to pass an argument to its constructor? Say you have a member `var` with a constructor that takes an `int`:

```
 Mother::Mother() :
   var(1)
 {
   // ..
 }
```

So the constructor of `var` is called before the body of the constructor of `Mother`, and you can pass arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

`Class::Class()` is not a unary operator - it is the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) of the class named `Class`. In other words, it is the code that gets executed when you have a statement such as:

```
Class my_instance;
```

or

```
Class another_instance();
```

the code in a default constructor typically initializes data fields or allocates system resources. The counterpart of the default constructor (or of any constructor really) is the *Destructor*, denoted `Class::~Class()` - which typically releases resources. Of course, constructors and destructors can be made to do all sorts of things - they have bodies just like any other function.

I'm not quite sure this helps you with the code example you gave (with the `msg()` method) - but that's what you started your question with, so I hope this helps.